# Mouse Click On a Particular Coordinate in an Active Window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-10, coordinates

I need to perform mouse click on a particular element in a window. I have calculated the coordinates of that element in my system and written a code to perform mouse click on that particular coordinate.

The code works fine for my machine. However, if I run it on a different machine the click operation is performed in a different position. It's because the screen size is different. How do I perform the mouse click on the same element in any machine regardless of window size. Is there any other way to locate an element on the screen? like percentage instead of pixels? Will it work?

```
RECT rect;
GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
int x = rect.left;
int y = rect.top;
SetCursorPos(x + 570, y + 450);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

In the above code I have set the cursor position with respect to my system. The element's XY coordinate is different for other machines with bigger screens. Any hint would be of much help.

Comment: Is this element a standard Windows UI widget or some third-party UI element? If it's third-party, it might still have automation/accesibility support.

Comment: @chris It's a standard Windows UI element. To be precise, it's a link in control panel window to open the next page.

Comment: That code is wrong. You need to send two events. One for the mouse down. One for the mouse up. And you need to use SendInput, as explained in the documentation. Rather than faking input you should prefer to use UI Automation.

Comment: 570 and 450 seem to be pretty big values, so I assume that the "link" is a "child" element. But, if the child is not itself a window, you should use UI Automation.